# Losing my session scope in IE and also in Chrome Incognito mode

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

Everything is working fine in Chrome and Firefox, but if I use Incognito mode, then I lose my session scope navigating from one hyperlink to the next. Internet Explorer is also not working.

Application.cfc:

```
component {
    this.name = 'sessionScope'
    this.SessionManagement = true
    this.sessionTimeout = CreateTimeSpan(0,0,45,0)
}
```

Index.cfm:

```
<html>
<body>
<cfdump var="#session#">
</body>
</html>
```

cfid keeps changing each time I refresh the page.

This is a Lucee install, but I've added the ColdFusion tag to reach a wider audience.

Comment: If I use Chrome, the cfid stays the same. But if I go Incognito it changes every time I navigate to a new link. The same with Internet Explorer.

Comment: Phillip I know this is not very helpful but I have lots of sites using the same basic application setup you have there running on Lucee and they all work fine in Chrome Incognito not losing the session scope between page loads. Don't think it will be it, but have you tried a different "name"?

Comment: Thanks @andrewdixon. Yeah, this proof-of-concept is using a different name than where it first manifested itself. I have also tried changing the setting from 'memory' to a datasource, just to try different options. And right now I'm rebooting the server.

Comment: I wonder if I included cfid in the url scope if that would help IE? Also [take a look at this bugbase](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3354476) from Adobe.

Comment: Does Lucee have the option of using J2EE sessions like Adobe's version does? It might help to use that instead of the standard cfid/cftoken.

Comment: Thanks @Miguel-F! That fixed it!

Comment: Cool. Glad that worked.

Comment: @PhillipSenn, you should mark Miguel's answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*promoted from the comments for better visibility*

Does Lucee have the option of using J2EE sessions like Adobe's version does? It might help to use that instead of the standard cfid/cftoken.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up setClientCookies=true

Comment: The cookie scope is different from the session scope.